# Symfony 3 - How to change configuration values at runtime

Tags: symfony

What is the best practice way to handle changes to configuration parameters (kept in yml) that have to happen at runtime?

I am working on a site where the owner wants to change various settings in his admin back end.
For example, enabling/disabling the confirmation email and link sent by FOS User bundle when a new user registers for an account.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Why not just change the values in the files directly (and clear cache afterward)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those operations you need the use Compiler Pass.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Here sample Custom Compiler pass;

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-separate-compiler-passes

Here is a good example for compiler passes; ( Usually using with service tags )

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html